# How can I add a class to the "action" item in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I can't seem to find the solution to this (maybe?) simple question anywhere.

I have a link that, when clicked, needs to have a class added to it. I have an action set up like so:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" {{action "addClass"}}>Link</a>
```

JS:

```
App.PageController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    addClass: function() {
      // SOMETHING HERE
    }
});
```

I tried using "addClass" but that doesn't work – plus I'm not sure how to reference the item on which the action is placed (usually it would be "this" but that refers to the action, I think?).

Comment: In this case `this` inside `addClass` refers to the controller. And as answered below, this is a use case for a `view`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a use case for an Ember View.

You can define your view like this:

```
App.ClassLinkView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'a',
    classNameBindings: ['myClass'],
    template: Handlebars.compile('Link'),
    click: function() {
        this.set('myClass', true);
    }
});
```

Then instead of your link, you can put this in your template, in order to render the view:

```
{{view "class-link"}}
```

Alternatively  (if you use an old version of Ember):

```
{{view App.ClassLinkView}}
```

Some explanation won't hurt. A view provides a way to encapsulate HTML content and to handle interactions. Let's break it down:

- Because of the `tagName`attribute, opening `<a>` and closing `</a>` will enclose the view's content, which is defined by the `template` attribute.
- The `click` attribute receives a function which will be executed on a `click`event.
- The function bound to the `click`event sets a `myClass` attribute on the view to true. `this` references the view itself (not its element).
- Because `myClass` is defined in the `classNameBindings` array, it is *not* added to the view element (the `<a>` tag) by default. But when the corresponding attribute of the view is true, the corresponding class is added to the view's element. **Note:** your `a` element will be assigned the class `my-class` and not `myClass` because of naming conventions in Ember.
- Also note that, because of the said naming conventions (really useful as you'll see by yourself!), Ember knows that `{{view "class-link"}}` is supposed to render an `App.ClassLinkView`.

To have this example run, you must include the *full* Handlebars (i.e. `handlebars.min.js`, not `handlebars.runtime.min.js`), because it contains the template compiler.

This code in action, and a little more, [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benoithubert/3obqLj4p/). More on views, and specifically, HTML attributes, in the [Ember.View guide](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#toc_html-code-class-code-attribute).